# RSS Auto Discovery

Tags: xml, html, rss, feed

I've been doing web dev for years, but this is my first jump into XML.  I've created an RSS feed and I cannot figure out how to get the browser to "discover" my feed and display the little RSS icon in the address bar.  The website in question is: http://www.aurorafxstudios.com/blog and my RSS feed is at: http://www.aurorafxstudios.com/blog/rss.php ...any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The icon appears in my address bar. Maybe you are using a browser that doesn't support RSS auto discovery. It isn't very fashionable these days.

Comment: Hmmm, that's weird.  I saw it once, switched tabs, came back and it was gone.  I'm in Safari 5, though I've testing in latest versions of Firefox and Chrome as well.  I'll put a manual RSS link up as well, but it'd be nice to see the RSS link pop up :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The 'official' version of the feed auto-discovery mechanism can be found at http://www.rssboard.org/rss-autodiscovery.

Assuming you have one or more discovery links published (MIME type depends on feed format):

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="human-readable label" href="http://www.aurorafxstudios.com/blog/rss.php" />
```

You can verify its presence in a number of ways. For example in IE 9 you can hit Alt + T (Tools) and verify your discovery link is listed under the *Feed Discovery* menu option.

Many consumers of your feed are going to retrieve it via a feed reader, most of which will accept the URL of your web site and locate the feeds you publish via the discovery link(s) and then present them to the end user. You might consider using a feed reader to verify your discovery links work.

As long as you follow the specification I would not worry about the variety of behaviors that you will see exhibited by different browsers.

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely take a look at that website.  It seems my RSS feed is recognizable by an RSS reader, just by entering my http://www.aurorafxstudios.com/blog/ URL.  This means my discovery link should be valid.  It's too bad I can't see the little RSS icon in the address bar, but like you said maybe it's just a weird browser behaviour as my browser recognizes other blog RSS feeds fine :(  PS. I don't have access to IE9 as I still only have XP.  Could anyone test this for me?

Answer (score 2):

Add the following within your 'head' tag.

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Name of Your Feed" href="http://www.aurorafxstudios.com/blog.xml" />
```